# why is MrSystem.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: dsadasd keep apearring?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

case 2:

```
                if (jk.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Mr" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Mr" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Mrs" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Ms" + name;
                    }
                }
                txbx1.Text = result;
                break;
```

this is the code i use here, but 
whenever click the button this keep appearing
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: dsndaslkdna.
i have try change it with txbx1 without .Text but i only become error can any one help with this?

Comment: What is `name`?

Comment: Provide click event handler's full code please

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code and seeing what it does? I don't think we have enough code to help.

Comment: thanks for helping but i kind of solved the problem accidentally XD

Comment: i just need to add .Text after name so it became result = "Ms" + name.Text;

Answer (score 0):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result;

```
        //combobox : lg,Sex,stat
        //textbox : name,show
        //button : button1

        switch (lg.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Bapak" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Mas" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Ibu" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Mbak" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
            case 1:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Xiansheng" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Xiansheng" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Taitai" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Xiaojie" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
            case 2:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Mr" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Mr" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Mrs" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Ms" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
            case 3:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "San" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Kun" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "San" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Chan" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
            case 4:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Ssi" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Hyung" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Ssi" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Noona" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
            case 5:

                if (Sex.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Monsieur" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Monsieur" + name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        result = "Madame" + name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Mademoiselle" + name;
                    }
                }
                show.Text = result;
                break;
        }
```

here the full one

Comment: thanks for helping but i kind of solved the problem accidentally XD     
i just need to add .Text after name so it became result = "Ms" + name.Text;

Comment: well i kinda solve the previous one

i have another question how can i make validation on that code
i have 3 combo box inside each one are 
Sex : male, female
stat : married, single
language : english, chinese, korean, japan, etc

also one textbox to fill name and another one to show the result

how can i make validation where if dont fill the name textbox , result textbox gonna show error
and result textbox gonna show error too , if nothing in combobox is choosen in otherword left as it is

can anyone made the code???